# Is there a way to clear the variables read using source < (grep = ...)?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, unset

It's possible to read variables from the `.ini` file with `source <(grep = test.ini)`:

```
$ cat test.ini 
[head]
  shoulders=/hahaha/
  knees=/lololol/
  toes=/kekeke/

$ source <(grep = test.ini)

$ echo $shoulders
/hahaha/

$ echo $knees
/lololol/

$ echo $toes
/kekeke/
```

I can manually clear variables read from the `source <(grep = ...)` command, e.g.

```
$ unset toes
$ echo toes
```

**But is there a way to automatically track which variables are added from the `source` command and unset them all together?**

Comment: Is it allowed to re-use the ini file ?

Comment: It may not be safe to source in an `ini` file like this.

Comment: Why isn't it safe to source an ini file?

Comment: Sure, it's fine to reuse the ini file.

Answer (score 1):

```
unset $(awk -F\= '/=/ { printf gensub(" ","","g",$1)" " }' test.ini)
```

Use awk to create a list of the variables being set and then use this output to run the unset. We use gensub to get rid of any spaces around the variables being set.

Comment: Never do `printf $field`, always do `printf "%s", $field` instead. Imagine the difference when `$field` contains printf formatting characters like `%s`. You should also mention that's gawk-specific due to gensub().

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this sort of thing is terribly unreliable.  But you could do something like:

```
set | grep -v ^_ > /tmp/original-vars  # record variables
source <(grep = test.ini)              # read from init file

# now, compare current variables assigned with the original and unset
# those that were not originally assigned while attempting
# to mask out some common internal variables that bash sets but making
# no claims at robustness or safety:
set | grep -v ^_ | diff -u - /tmp/original-vars \
  | awk '/^-/ && NR>1{print $2}' FS=[=-] \
  | while read var; do unset $var; done
```

YMMV, reader beware, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason for "varying millage"? Any example(s)?

Comment: @alvas This is a horribly non-robust approach, and I make absolutely no claims that it will correctly unset only those variables assigned when sourceing the file or that it will unset all of them.  Hence the disclaimers.